# Upgrade a custom Joomla 1.0 component to Joomla 3.2. Is it possible?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

I'm upgrading a Joomla 1.0 website to Joomla 3.2. In this website, some years ago we created a custom component. Now, for the new website, I need a component with the same functionality. Is to possible to upgrade the existing component, or must I create a new 3.2 component?

Comment: You can upgrade your existing component, however it will have to be completely reqritten as the coding standards have completely changed since Joomla 1.0. I think to make life easier, you would probably be better off developing the component from scratch.

Comment: Even without changes in code standards, PHP has changed so much